# Ag grid - Master/detail,keep detail rows permanently open

Tags: javascript, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

For Ag grid Master/Detail, is there a way to make detail rows open by default? With no option to close them?

Comment: You should add a concrete example to your question to let people better understand what you exactly mean and what you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost, you can iterate through all the master rows on your ag-grid, and on each node, you make use of the `setExpanded()` method and set the parameter to `true`. This will result in all rows to be opened. This can be handled on the `onGridReady` event.

```
params.api.forEachNode(node => {
  node.setExpanded(true);
})
```

As for keeping it open permanently with no option to close them, one way to get around this would be to hide the arrow icon which toggles the rows. To achieve that, we can overwrite the default CSS by setting the `display` property to `none`. In addition, you might need to use the `!important` declaration.

```
.ag-theme-balham .ag-cell .ag-icon {
  display: none!important;
}
```

I have created a [demo](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/8t4hPw3Qx3uCzfbu).

Comment: Thank yoy @wentjun, looks like a good solution, I'll try this!